# sending data from textarea to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get text area to post to my array and then be stored in the MySQL Database. Every element of the form works except for the "textarea" part Here is the code I have... Any help is appreciated! Thank You!!

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            First name*:<br>
            <input type="text" class="standard" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $user_data['first_name']; ?>">
        </li>
        <li>
            Last name:<br>
            <input class="standard" type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $user_data['last_name']; ?>">
        </li>
        <li>
            Email*:<br>
            <input class="standard" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $user_data['email']; ?>">
        </li>
        <li>
            Phone Number:<br>
            <input class="standard" type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $user_data['phone']; ?>">
        </li>
        <li>
            About Me:<br>
            <textarea id="textarea" maxlength="1000" name="summary" value="<?php echo $user_data['summary']; ?>"></textarea>
            <div id="textarea_feedback"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            Account type:<br>
            <select name="type">
                <option value="0" <?php if ($user_data['type'] == 0) echo "selected"; ?>>Employee</option>
                <option value="1" <?php if ($user_data['type'] == 1) echo "selected"; ?>>Employer</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Update">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

So the "About Me" textarea is not working.

Here is the php sending it to the database:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
echo 'Your details have been updated!';
} else {
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {

    $update_data = array(
        'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name'     => $_POST['last_name'],
        'email'         => $_POST['email'],
        'type'          => $_POST['type'],
        'phone'         => $_POST['phone'],
        'summary'       => $_POST['summary']
    );

    update_user($session_user_id, $update_data);
    header('Location: settings.php?success');
    exit();

} else if (empty($errors) === false) {
    echo output_errors($errors);
}
?>
```

Here is the function sending to database.

```
function user_data($user_id) {
$data = array();
$user_id = (int)$user_id;

$func_num_args = func_num_args();
$func_get_args = func_get_args();

if ($func_num_args > 1) {
    unset($func_get_args[0]);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` LIKE $user_id"));

    return $data;
}
}
```

Comment: textareas don't use the `value` property, instead the value is the content of the tag.

Comment: I don't see any SQL to support the question.

Comment: Plus, an edit was made `form action="" method="post">` to `<form action="" method="post">` - So, if that's what you were actually using, then that's part of the problem.

Comment: 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'type', 'phone' all work well. It is just the text area with the name 'summary that isn't

Comment: This is a select, not an update. Also please do not use the mysql extension, instead resort to the more secure mysqli or pdo extensions

Comment: ^ yeah...where's the code for that? I don't see any INSERT or UPDATE. So, my first comment still applies. No code to support the question.

Comment: I got the working answer, apologies for the lack of information in the qu. I thought I had added all releveant information. I had added the code for the function which handles the SELECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<textarea id="textarea" maxlength="1000" name="summary" value="<?php echo $user_data['summary']; ?>"></textarea>
```

Change that line to:

```
<textarea id="textarea" maxlength="1000" name="summary" ><?php echo $user_data['summary']; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a typo at the name attribute for your textarea. You wrote name-"summary" instead of name="summary".